# Add html code before checkout header title on WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I need a function to add a **`HTML`** code before **checkout header title** on WooCommerce. I would like to add a process bar.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Checkout title is located in the header.php of your theme. So there is no any WooCommerce hooks for that.

So you can accomplish that editing the **`header.php`** file of your active child theme (or active theme) using [the dedicated WooCommerce conditional tag **`is_checkout()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/):

```
<?php if( is_checkout() ): ?>
    <!-- HERE GOES YOUR HTML CODE DISPLAYED ONLY IN CHECKOUT HEADER -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

**ADDITIONAL UPDATE:**

> For checkout only **and not order recieved (thank you)**:

```
<?php if( is_checkout() && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ): ?>
    <!-- HERE GOES YOUR HTML CODE DISPLAYED ONLY IN CHECKOUT HEADER -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to show my html code in checkout only and not in checkout/order-received? or Is there a way to show my html code in checkout and another html code in checkout/order-received?

Comment: Hi is me again, 

Sorry to keep bothering you but I need help. I just update my woocommerce storefront theme with I’m using a child theme too. The thing is I’m using Browser caching for .htaccess and now I have a problem that costumers cached browsers don’t see the new style.css update. how can I change style.css name to something like stylenew.css so browsers can can see it as a new style file? or can I use a function to do it. I have seen some function like wp_enqueue_style but I can’t figure out how to make it work.

Thanks;
Elliot

Comment: First as you have enough reputation now, you can upvote this answer (please). This is going to be complicated as in child theme the CSS are always located in that style.css file. Is complicate to help in this comments. So you can try to catch me on Skype chat, my ID is `marsloic`… This will be more accurate.